# PHP function get wrong value with SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

If suppose my ID is 'ANS152488' than i got role='ANS152488' and id='JytJRCsn'. but encryptId() function is not working fine because correct ans is 'QU5TMTUyNDg4' instead of 'JytJRCsn'.

why base64 not work???

Query -

```
SELECT FNAME, LNAME, '<a id=".encryptId("'+ID+'")." rel=".testingId("'+ID+'")." class=\"btn btn-info\">Click</a>' As [Status] FROM UserInfo
```

PHP Function -

```
function encryptId($param){
  $res = base64_encode($param);
  return $res;
}

//For Testing Purpose - 
function testingId($param){
 return $param;
}
```

Comment: you can't put PHP into your MySQL queries

Comment: @Pattle but function is still working in sql query, only getting wrong answer if the value encode to base64. any others way to represent???

Comment: Hint: `base64_encode("'+ID+'")` = `'JytJRCsn'`. Try `base64_encode(ID)` instead.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage can you show me perfect sql query with php function???

Comment: @RajeevRanjan yes sir, i got the correct result with my testing function testingId() but when i use base64 encode function then always i'm getting particular field name.

Comment: @RohitSutharMumbai its always better to have records first then its easy to make available for output.

Comment: @RohitSutharMumbai No, I can't, because you've only posted a fragment of your SQL query here. The problem is that you want to calculate the base64 encoding of your `ID` constant, but instead you are calculating the base64 encoding of a string consisting of a single quotation mark, a plus sign, the letters "I" and "D", and another plus sign and quotation mark. Why you're bothering to apply base64 encoding to the ID value in the first place is a complete mystery to me. And why is ID defined as a constant?

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
<?php
 $query= "select * form  UserInfo " 

 $result=mysql_query($query);

 if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)

  {
   while($rows=mysql_fetch_array())

  { ?>

<a id="<?php echo encryptId(rows['ID'])?>" rel="<?php echo testingId(rows['ID'])?> class=\"btn btn-info\">Click</a>

 <?php

   }
  } 
  ?>
```